# Which is faster and more preferred when keeping track of a row's status?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization

Let's say for instance you have a table which contains orders and this table has a column which keeps track if the order is either pending/shipped/denied/approved. Which is the better way to keep the status for the record?

Option one. Keeping the status as a string in an indexed column.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | customer_id | status | created_at | shipped_at |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |            1| pending| . . .      | . . .      |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

or
Option two. Have a separate table which contains the possible statuses and have the status column be a foreign key which points to this table which contains the statuses.

```
Table: Statuses
----------------
| id | name    |
----------------
| 1  | pending |
----------------
| 2  | approved|
----------------
| 3  | denied  |
----------------
| 4  | shipped |
----------------

Table: Orders
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | customer_id | status | created_at | shipped_at |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |            1|       1| . . .      | . . .      |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

In my opinion, the first is simpler but would become slow if the table becomes massive while the second would be faster in that case.

Comment: There’s also enumerations. But it’s not that clear cut what is faster and in what operations.

Comment: Considering the size of table will grow over the time. Fetching the data using the join will take more time. For me it is the first option.

Comment: If you are happy with dirty data go for option 1 if you prefer to keep things tight got for option 2.(a foreign key check isn't that expensive anyway) AND I would keep a history of all changes to order and order details...

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because of the inevitable slew of downvotes but MySQL [ENUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) types are actually really well suited to this particular application and will save space and the time penalty of a `JOIN`.

Comment: Performancewise, there's not much in it, but those of us who cherish data integrity would opt for 2 (even over ENUM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option two is better, because:

1. it will consume less space
2. Search also will work quicker with numbers than with a strings
3. In case you will later  want to change "approved" to "temporary approve" you will need to change it in one place, no across your whole data
4. You also can do something like `WHERE status > 2` which is impossible with strings

Probably many more reasons exist, it's just first came to my mind. And I see no reason to use first option.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer is: it depends.

As already said, option 2 looks better because of space consumption, integrity and evolutivity.

But I'm a strong believer of the YAGNI principle: if it's not needed yet (let's say if you don't plan to add more statuses, to make them configurable or have a lot of data for the next years), it's probably not needed and it's perfectly ok to build option 1.

And it will be ok to change data structure in a few years if needed. Maybe in a different way, to fulfill needs you can't foresee right now.

Answer (score 0):

"Better" is highly dependent on opinion. You could define what you mean by "better" - which attributes do you want to optimize for?

In terms of "faster" - relational databases (including MySQL) are really, really good at joins. So good that in most cases, when you are joining on foreign keys, there is no measurable performance impact, even with tens or hundreds of millions of records. So, I don't think option 1 is "faster" unless you reach Amazon scale.

Other attributes you may consider are "easy to maintain". Option 1 is open to bugs, because you have to be sure that every bit of code that wants to know whether an order is "pending" includes the right bit of text in the query. A simple typo could mean you stop shipping orders to your customers. It's likely you'll want to create some moderately complex business rules about the transitions between states - "do not allow an order to transition from denied to shipped", and you'll have *lots* of opportunity for typos. If you are worried about "easy to maintain", either option 2 or using an enum is probably better.

Another attribute may be "easy to extend". Right now, your statuses have no additional attributes, but that may not remain the case. For instance, you may decide to store the amount of time an order may stay in a given status, or the roles which are allowed to override a status change. Again, in that case, option 2 is probably easier to work with.